# Using covered text on an annotator in UIMA RUTA

Tags: uima, ruta

I would like to use the covered text of an annotation as in input in the subsequent code (eg, to name another annotation). Is it possible to recall the covered text and mention it again in the code? For example, if I have the following text -

Heading1
.............(Text 1)

Heading2
..............(Text 2)

Code:

DECLARE Header
"Heading1" {-> MARK(Header)}

DECLARE Text_Heading1 (where Heading1 = covered text of header)

Is it possible to do this in Ruta?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE Header;
DECLARE TextHeading (STRING headerText);

"Heading." -> Header;
Header{-> TextHeading, TextHeading.headerText=Header.ct};
```

"ct" refers to the covered text of the matched annotation as a feature. If the annotations should be created at different positions, you may need to use additional language elements like a string variable, MATCHEDTEXT, and CREATE/GATHER or label expressions.